# MongoDB: MongoClient.isConnected() disappeared on mongodb v.4.0

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I used MongoClient.isConnected() method on version 3.6 of mongodb but now the method does not seem to exist anymore. Why?

If the expression `MongoClient.isConnected()` is not clear I mean this:

```js
const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, options?);

client.isConnected(); // does not exist on type MongoClient
```

I am using Typescript, and of course I installed mongodb and its types (even if it is not necessary anymore with mongodb v.4.0).

How do I get to know if my database is connected or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the check via callbacks, which you can pass as parameters in the `.conenct` Method. See [the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html).

Comment: Sure, but in a unit testing context, handling it via callbacks is not a good thing. Is it ?

Comment: Imo, it depends on what you want to test. If you want to test the connection speed performance, then it wouldn't be a good solution. But if you want to test, if the database is reachable, i can't think of a reason why handling it with a callback would have a negative impact.

Comment: I'll try but I'm still searching for another option :)

Comment: How would one do this?