# mongo.isConnected alternative for node driver v4+

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any alternative for the deprecated MongoClient.isConnected in the native Node JS MongoDB driver?

I [read somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000064/mongodb-mongoclient-isconnected-disappeared-on-mongodb-v-4-0) that one can handle the check via callbacks, which one can pass as parameters in the .connect Method [(See the docs.)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html)
However, I wasn't able to successfully do that.

Comment: mongoClient has an event when connects to server. client.on('connected', ...)

Comment: thanks a lot, is there an equivalent for disconnection?

Comment: yes, in official docs you will find all events available (on connect, on disconnect, on error, etc)

Answer (score -3):

You can connect to MongoDB with the mongoose.connect() method.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp');
```

Install Mongoose from the command line using npm:

```
$ npm install mongoose --save
```

Refer to my MongoDB + Node example:

https://github.com/juhisri211/node-mongo-app/blob/master/index.js

For more details about Mongoose, please refer to official documentation:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: The question is not asking how to connect to Mongodb.  It is asking how to verify that a mongodb nodejs driver client instance is currently connected.